# glibmm-2.4 install not detected on OS X

Tags: glib, glibmm

I am building an application from source, Ardour specifically.
During the build config process it exits with the following error:

```sh
Checking for 'glibmm-2.4' >= 2.32.0
['/opt/local/bin/pkg-config', 'glibmm-2.4 >= 2.32.0', '--cflags', '--libs', 'glibmm-2.4']
err: Package glibmm-2.4 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `glibmm-2.4.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'glibmm-2.4' found
Package glibmm-2.4 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `glibmm-2.4.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'glibmm-2.4' found
```

I use [homebrew](http://brew.sh) for package management,so I installed `glibmm` and `glib`.
However, the build config process still fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out:
When using `brew`

Add

`export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/glib/<VERSION>/lib/pkgconfig` to end of `~/.bash_profile`.
Then run `source ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Did it work for you the compiling of Ardour I am having the same problem but hesitating whether to do this in case I screw something else.

Comment: I managed to compile Ardour into an executable binary, but it crashed upon execution.